# PC won't start, PSU buzzing/humming

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, computer-building, amd-athlon

I have an MSI K7N2 motherboard with an Athlon 3200+ XP. I have been running it in an old Cooler Master case and it has been OK for at least 10 years. About a year ago, it broke down, with something making a faint buzz in the machine. I tried replacing the 350W PSU with another, a 400 watt, in hope of bringing it back to life (and to the future). But the buzz was still there. I gave up, having built a new machine but I revisited this mobo now (breadboarding only with CPU) but the fans still don't come on. I repeat that I have *tried* with a different PSU and both buzz. Now, the 400W PSU powers my i5 machine (a gaming computer, but I don't game) so it is okay. Is it possible to fix it somehow? I think there is a short circuit.

TL;DR: PSU buzzing even with a breadboard, no fan spin, tried another good PSU.

UPDATE: When the case speaker is plugged in, it makes the same noise as the PSU. (No pattern or special signal, just *noise*.) Also, occasionally when I power the PSU off while plugged into the mobo and power socket, all fans (CPU, chipset, PSU) move/jerk for a split second.